# Exclude Properties from merge in Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm fetching some Items from a REST Api and Caching it locally through Core Data. The Core Data Objects/NSManagedObjects holds a property, which the json doesn't.

F.e. I have a isFavorite property on the NSManagedObject which doesn't exist in JSON:

```
struct JsonItem: Decodable {
    var title: String?
    ...
}

// The generated NSManagedObject Subclass
extension Item {
    ...
    @NSManaged public var title: String?
    @NSManaged public var isFavorite: Bool
}
```

I set the default value of this isFavorite property to **false** and the MergePolicy to `NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy`.

When I now update the data from the Api the isFavorite Bool gets overwritten/set to false. The data gets updated by this Code:

```
func fetchItems(objectContext: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Void {
    Api.shared.getItems(completion: { items in
        guard let itemList = items else { return }
                    
        for item: JsonItem in itemList {
            let newItem = Item(context: objectContext)
            newItem.title = item.title
            ...
                            
            do {
                try objectContext.save()
                
            } catch {
                ...
            }
        }
    })
}
```

How can I exclude this property from getting updated?

Comment: How do you „update the data from the API“?

Comment: ok. you say your default for isFavorite is *false*. you also say that it gets overwritten/set to *false*. So it is not really getting changed? is it?

Comment: If I set the value to true and then update it's false. Expected Behaviour is Fetch API -> mark Items as Favorite -> Fetch Api -> marked Items are still Favorite

Comment: But you are creating _new_ Core Data objects from the json data so nothing gets updated. If you want to update your existing objects you need to do a fetch first based on some unique attribute(s) and modify the fetched object

Comment: As @JoakimDanielson points out you are not updating Items you are always creating new Items

Comment: I read up on NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy that I haven’t used myself and maybe the above can work if you have defined a unique constraint for the entity, have you?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that. Yes, there is a Unique Constraint on the Item ID. I use the IDs from the REST API, since they're not changing.

Comment: How do you set the default value for `isFavourite` - in code, or in the model?

Comment: @pbasdf In the Model.

Comment: My only suggestion is to make isFavourite optional, and leave the default value blank (nil).  Don’t know if that will work.

Answer (score 1):

From your description it sounds like you need to change your merge policy. `NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy` says that if there's a conflict, values from the new object win. Since the new objects have `isFavorite = false`, that always wins out and `true` values in the store get erased. If you use `NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy`, that says that when conflicts exist, values from the persistent store win. So if you had an existing object with `isFavorite = true` and an update with the default `isFavorite = false`, the existing object's value wins.

Comment: Changing the Merge Policy to NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy will keep the Data from the Persistence Store. In that Case no Data can be updated. I want to exclude some properties from getting updated (Update all Properties, but keep isFavorite)

Comment: Changing the merge policy will mean that any time two values are different, the version you have in the persistent store will win out over the new incoming value. That would solve the problem you describe, because if you have changed the value of `isFavorite` then your changed value will not be removed. You cannot exclude a specific property from the process but you can solve the problem you describe with a different merge policy.